# How to read PostgreSQL wal file data? Is there is any command to convert PostgreSQL binary to readable text format?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to read PostgreSQL `wal` file. Its a binary file and I am not able to read `wal` file data in text format. Can anyone help me for this.
Is there any command or something to read the `wal` file data?

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you really still using Postgres 9.2? That version [is no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should plan your upgrade to a supported version now.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, there are two options in Postgres for presenting WALs in some human-readable format:

1. `pg_waldump` [utility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/pgwaldump.html), but it is available only in 9.3+. You can try using `pg_waldump` from 9.3 with 9.2 WALs, but I am not sure in success. It may work, since there should not be any new WAL record types in 9.2, which do not exist in 9.3. Note: `pg_waldump` was called `pg_xlogdump` until Postgres 10.0
2. Also it is possible to utilize [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/logicaldecoding-explanation.html), but it is available since 9.4. Anyway, with logical decoding one can use [various plugins](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logical_Decoding_Plugins) like `wal2json` to export records in the human-readable format. Note: logical decoding may do not decode every WAL record, it is mostly about DML (insert/update/delete)

Thus, I would strongly recommend to upgrade your cluster to Postgres 9.4 at least.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wal2json, but it only work for pg9.4+

https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json