# Is there a way to show everything that was changed in a PostgreSQL database during a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, diff

I often have to execute complex sql scripts in a single transaction on a large **PostgreSQL** database and I would like to verify everything that was changed during the transaction.

> Verifying each single entry on each table "by hand" would take ages.

Dumping the database before and after the script to plain sql and using `diff` on the dumps isn't really an option since each dump would be about `50G` of data.

Is there a way to show all the data that was added, deleted or modified during a single transaction?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123145

Comment: Is there a way to see the deleted entries as well? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Depending on how you want to see the data, it may also be worth looking at the [WAL (Write Ahead Log)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828327#answer-55829005) could help if using PostgreSQL 9.3+.

Comment: On Postgres 10+ [transition relations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). [Example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) Example 42.7. Auditing with Transition Tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, What are you looking for is the most searchable thing on the internet when it comes to capturing Database changes. It is a kind of version control we can say.

But as long as I know, sadly there are no **in-built** approaches are available in **PostgreSQL** or **MySql**. But you can overcome it by setting/adding some triggers for your most usable operations.

You can create some backup **schemas**, and **tables** to capture your changes that are changed(updated), created, or deleted.

In this way you can achieve what you want. I know this process is fully manual, But really effective.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to add new tables and triggers since I've got a lot of tables but it seems like there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to analyze the script's behaviour only sporadically, then the easiest approach would be to change server configuration parameter `log_min_duration_statement` to `0` and then back to any value it had before the analysis. Then all of the script activity will be written to the instance log.
This approach is not suitable if your storage is not prepared to accommodate this amount of data, or for systems in which you don't want sensitive client data to be written to a plain-text log file.

Comment: You don't need to restart Postgres to change that setting. A simple `select pg_reload_conf();`  is enough.

Comment: My bad! For some reason I though that the parameter was not dynamic.